# QUdpSocket и Socks5 proxy

Tags: qt, proxy, udp, socks5

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь использовать QUdpSocket с Socks5 proxy, но ничего не выходит, при подключении всё время ошибки. Делаю так:
В main:

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::Socks5Proxy);
proxy.setHostName("37.59.13.53");
proxy.setPort(45912);
QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

В конструкторе класса сокета:

```
sampSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
bool is = socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost);//Пробовал все возможные вариации, итог один.
```

[image: Скриншот программы]

Иногда выдаёт ошибку

> "Connection to proxy closed prematurely"

Все прокси рабочие, проверял web-чекером и использовал их в telegram.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

**UPD**
Проблема по всей видимости в самих прокси. Но найти прокси, работающие с UDP практически нереально....

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setProxy

а если так:

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::Socks5Proxy);
proxy.setHostName("ip address");
proxy.setPort(1080);
udpSocket.setProxy(proxy);
```

Comment: Пробовал и так. Как оказалось, причина в плохих прокси. Купил нормальные, но теперь новая ошибка "Network operation timed out". Рекомендации из документации использовал.

Comment: я тестировал программу свою на своём локальном прокси/соксе, чтобы быть уверенным, что проблема не во внешних прокси. Поставьте любой прокси-сервер на localhost и используйте его.